# Can you upload 2 separate ipa's pointing to two targets in the Appstore. One for iPhone and one for iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

We have a build version specific to iPhone and another build specific to iPad.

Is it possible to upload both these builds to the AppStore that point to the specific device? If so, how?

Comment: You have to make 2 different application in iTunes store, with different bundle identifier.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create 2 separate apps on the iTunes Connect and Developer Portal with 2 separate bundle IDs, you can assemble them from 1 Xcode project if you wish using multiple targets.

Don't forget to make specific device requirements in the target settings, so each target can only be run on one family of device.

Comment: Also, be aware that Apple will test that your iPhone app runs on an iPad in iPhone emulation mode. It is recommended that you make a Universal app rather than separate iPhone and iPad apps.

Comment: We don’t do it now (universal app) because we support different iOS versions for iPad and iPhone